# Different multiple hostnames in locust

Tags: locust

How to use the multiple hostnames(URL) in the locust script? I have a scenario where i need to get a token by hitting different API and use that token in my script for hitting the other API

I tried using events in locust but not able to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`host` in Locust is just a convenience factor, allowing you to give some base URL once and then define relative URLs off of that if you choose to make things a bit easier, less verbose in some cases, and give you the ability to change the base URL (such as for different testing environments ) at runtime.

However, **using `host` and relative URLs is optional. All of Locust's clients can take a full URL.**

You can call a different API on a totally different host anytime you want by passing in the full URL. And you can do whatever you want in code to make that determination, like having a predefined dictionary of host1 relating to tokenAPI1, host2 to tokenAPI2, etc. Or building a URL based on some rules or naming convention and using that. And this can all be done in a single `task`, calling one API based on `host` and another with a full URL to another server elsewhere. It doesn't matter; Locust will run whatever code you give it. The docs and examples you see are often basic starting points to help introduce the Locust concepts to people but don't have to be limited to the basics in any way.